# Delphi InputBox for password entry?

Tags: delphi, mask, textinput, inputbox

Inputbox:

```
answer:=Inputbox('a','b','c');
```

works good, but I'm looking for a masked one, like a password box where you only see little stars instead of the typed characters.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can send a Windows message to the edit control created by `InputBox`, that will flag the edit control for password entry. Code below taken from http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1208:

```
const
   InputBoxMessage = WM_USER + 200;

type
   TForm1 = class(TForm)
     Button1: TButton;
     procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   private
     procedure InputBoxSetPasswordChar(var Msg: TMessage); message InputBoxMessage;
   public
   end;

var
   Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.InputBoxSetPasswordChar(var Msg: TMessage);
var
   hInputForm, hEdit, hButton: HWND;
begin
   hInputForm := Screen.Forms[0].Handle;
   if (hInputForm <> 0) then
   begin
     hEdit := FindWindowEx(hInputForm, 0, 'TEdit', nil);
     {
       // Change button text:
       hButton := FindWindowEx(hInputForm, 0, 'TButton', nil);
       SendMessage(hButton, WM_SETTEXT, 0, Integer(PChar('Cancel')));
     }
     SendMessage(hEdit, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, Ord('*'), 0);
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   InputString: string;
begin
   PostMessage(Handle, InputBoxMessage, 0, 0);
   InputString := InputBox('Input Box', 'Please Enter a Password', '');
end;
```

Comment: Wow! elegant way to defer execution :-)

Comment: This might be a dump question, but how do you know `Screen.Forms[0]` is the form created by `InputBox`?

Answer (score 42):

In XE2, `InputBox()` and `InputQuery()` were updated to natively support masking the `TEdit` input, although that feature has not been documented yet.  If the first character of the `APrompt` parameter is set to any value < `#32` then the `TEdit.PasswordChar` will be set to `*`, eg:

```
answer := InputBox('a', #31'b', 'c');
```

Comment: Now that's intuitive!

Comment: They went to the trouble of expanding `InputQuery()` (which `InputBox()` uses internally) with new parameters for multi-prompts and an `OnCloseQuery` callback, but they couldn't be bothered to create a new parameter for specifying password masking? The multi-prompts support per-prompt masking, but they could have made that interface more intuitive. Instead of using an array of strings with special lead characters, they should have used an array of records containing string/mask pairs. That would even have allowed future fields to be added for finer control over the `TEdit` controls. But nope.

Answer (score 9):

InputBox calls the InputQuery function in Dialogs, which creates the form dynamically.  You could always make a copy of this function and change the TEdit's PasswordChar property.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that Delphi includes such a thing out of the box. Maybe you can find one at http://www.torry.net/ or elsewhere in the net. Otherwise just write one yourself - shouldn't be that hard. :-) You can even look at the source code if you have a "big enough" Delphi version.

Uli.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone still needs a simple solution, here it is:

```
InputQuery('MyCaption', #0 + 'MyPrompt', Value); // <-- the password char '*' is used
```

That works because the InputQuery function has the following nested function:

```
function GetPasswordChar(const ACaption: string): Char;
begin
  if (Length(ACaption) > 1) and (ACaption[1] < #32) then
    Result := '*'
  else
    Result := #0;
end;
```

And it's called for every prompt:

```
PasswordChar := GetPasswordChar(APrompts[I]);
```

Therefore, if the first character in the APrompts is < #32 (ex. #0), the password char of the TEdit will be '*'.

**Tested on Delphi 10.4.** I'm not sure when was this introduced, I skipped from D6 straight to 10.4 and haven't tested on D6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use InputQuery instead of InputBox. When the TRUE argument is set, password field will be masked.

```
InputQuery('Authenticate', 'Password:',TRUE, value);
```

Some resource here; http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/dialogs/inputquery.html

Comment: Note: Does not work for Delphi. Seems to be a Lazarus-Only thing.