# Evaluate "Cancel" from inputbox in Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

using [`inputbox`](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Dialog_Examples#InputBox) in Lazarus/Free Pascal gives you a dialogue with "OK" and "Cancel".

Does pressing "cancel" do anything else then returning the default string (which would be the same if I press ok without entering anything in the input field)? Apparently It does so using [Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830562/delphi-7-how-to-use-inputbox)! The [doc for `inputbox`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/dialogs/inputbox.html) is down at the moment, so it's not possible to check there. Thanks!

Comment: In Delphi, `Cancel` returns false, while OK returns true. You use it like `if InputBox(....) then`.

Comment: @KenWhite using Lazarus `inputbox` doesn't return true when ok is pressed it returns the string that was typed into the input field (`InputQuery` has the behaviour you are describing)!

Comment: Lazarus is open source. `InputBox()` implementation contains only two lines of code: `Result := ADefault; InputQuery(ACaption, APrompt, Result);`

Comment: @Abelisto of course, completely forgot about the option to check in the source code myself! Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

InputBox() only returns a string. This string is the one edited and confirmed by the user, or the *default* passed as argument.

Companion to InputBox() is InputQuery(), which returns true or false depending whether the user confirmed or not. The actual string to show and confirm is passed as a *var* parameter, and is hence returned back.